# calling static function from constructor of same class

Tags: c++

can we call static function from constructor of same class.

```
class a{
    static void fun();
    a() {fun();}
};
```

it is giving an error while linking code. I am using visual studio C++, 2010.

Comment: did you provide function definition for `func()`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can - as long as you provide a function definition for the static function as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand the question.

If you provide a function definition as said by Billz and Ogni42, it will work.

The following code does compile, and work:

```
#include <iostream>

class a {
public:
  a() { fun(); }

private:
  static void fun();
};

void a::fun() {
  std::cout << "BOAP" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  a foo;
  return 0;
}
```